# Can you permanently True Polymorph into yourself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

Can a character *[true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* into itself (possibly after transforming into some other form first)? Possibly to [prevent aging](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64573/can-true-polymorph-be-used-repeatedly-to-never-age), [cure wounds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64577/can-true-polymorph-be-used-to-recover-from-diseases-or-curses), or [alter their original body](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64576/how-much-control-does-polymorph-true-polymorph-allow-over-aesthetics) in some way? Or as a means of reversing a True Polymorph someone permanently cast against them earlier? (ex a warrior is permanently transformed into a toad, and the party wizard shows up to permanently transform the warrior back into his regular self.)

Comment: Note that there's a far easier way to reverse a True Polymorph than by casting True Polymorph again:

"The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 Hit Points or dies. If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the transformation becomes permanent." 

Concentrating for the full hour causes the transformation's duration to become permanent, but it doesn't negate the 0 hit points clause. Just smack the toad, and the warrior will pop out slightly bruised.

Comment: @EttinaKitten are you sure about that? "If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the transformation lasts until it is dispelled." is the wording from the PHD/DNDBeyond. I don't think hitting them would do anything, but a Wizard powerful enough to True Polymorph you *should* also be powerful enough to Dispel the effect as required.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Short answer: Yes you can, but it could get complicated

Addressing the elements in reverse order:

### The Soul of a Warrior Trapped in a Toad's Body

> Can a character True Polymorph into itself as a means of reversing a True Polymorph someone permanently cast against them earlier?  (ex: A warrior is permanently transformed into a toad.  The party wizard shows up to permanently transform the warrior *back into his regular self*.)

First of all, his equipment's gone if you turn the toad back into a warrior.
p. 283 PHB, from the spell description.

> The target’s gear *melds into the new form*. The creature can’t activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment.

Secondly: what is the CR or character level of the toad?  When he got turned into a toad with the one hour concentration that made it permanent, that new form has new statistics, and has either a level or a CR bounded by how the spell operates.

> the target's game statistics are replaced by the new form statistics including also its mental ability scores  ...
>
> If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, the new form can be any kind you choose **whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target’s (or its level, if the target doesn’t have a challenge rating).**

If your warrior was ninth level, did he become a ninth level toad, a CR *X* toad, or what?  As a point of reference: a Giant toad is CR 1, a Giant Frog is CR 1/4, and a regular frog (close enough to a toad) is CR 0.

Once the level or CR of this toad is established (work with your DM) you can transform that "once a warrior, now a toad" into a warrior (himself?) with a CR equal to or less than the CR of its current form per the spell description.

There is a potential for bad news: what is the equivalent level of a CR=0 warrior?  A congressman?

> The target’s game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form. **It retains its alignment and personality.**

That last sentence opens the door to "kiss the frog and restore the prince inside."  If who you are is made up of your alignment and personality and your soul (you aren't dead, you are alive, it is YOU in there, and souls* are part of D&D 5e), then "You the toad" could be a level-X warrior *trapped in a toad's body*.

Your DM could rule yes or no on that.

- If DM rules no, it might take a wish spell to restore the warrior to
  his true self.
- But DM could rule yes based on *the soul of the warrior remaining intact* due to still being alive, albeit in a new form.

*Note on the soul, from 9th level Astral Projection spell:

> If the cord is cut—something that can happen only when an effect specifically states that it does — *your soul and body are separated, killing you instantly*.

From this we deduce that while still alive, your soul -- who you are -- remains with you regardless of what form you are in.  There's hope.  "Who's inside that new body?" is also addressed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62530/how-do-polymorph-like-spells-interact-with-spellcasting-capability/62533#62533) in the section with the title "The Vibe."

Now for the Generic question:

### Who's Really In There, Inside that Body?

> Can a character True Polymorph into itself (possibly after transforming into some other form first)?  Possibly to prevent aging, cure wounds, or alter their original body in some way?

Once the CR/Level issue noted above is resolved with the DM, yes, as long as whomever casts the spell can concentrate long enough to do it.  Once again:

> If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, the new form can be any kind you choose **whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target’s (or its level, if the target doesn’t have a challenge rating).**

Work that out with your DM and proceed.

For what it's worth, Jeremy Crawford(lead rules dev for 5e) [had this to say about who is in there](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/961395590486663173?s=20):

> A spell doesn't erase/suppress your memories unless the spell's text
> says it does.
> When the text of a spell, like polymorph, says you retain your personality after a transformation, that's a terse way of saying, "You're still you, despite the radical changes you undergo." #DnD

---

### Supporting point on it being "you" in there no matter what form you take.

There is a hint that "it's you in there!" in the "Creature to Object" element of the spell (p. 284 PHB) where a creature becomes an inanimate object for a while (not a permanent transformation).  "You" are in there but "...the creature has no memory of the time spent in this form ..."

This can be read as being due to inanimate objects having no mental abilities. (Remember, the new form's stats are now your stats). You were in there, body and soul, but the lack of mental traits rendered memory irrelevant ... more "in a coma" than "brain death." You come out of this "coma" alive and intact, with your stats, when the spell expires.

This interpretation, you *not being dead* when temporarily an object, is consistent with soul and body being bound together in a live character, however impaired in terms of stats.

If the change into an object is permanent ... that's another story, or another trope.

Work with your DM.

Comment: +1 for the post and discussion of a soul. However, I believe the spell states that anything so transformed keeps all its class levels and abilities. While a toad may not be capable of doing these things, the *class levels* remain. The changed physical attributes, however, could still affect the CR rating; do you have thoughts on that?

Comment: I had not considered the equipment issue. The gear melds into the new form; however, in a non-permanent True Polymorph, it is my expectation that the gear transforms back when the creature does. If correct, that would indicate some "record" of the gear still exists, though whether that is useful for a subsequent transformation, I don't know. The wizard *can* provide new equipment, but probably only the standard for the new form's class (toad becomes warrior with chain armor, sort of thing. No magic items).

Comment: In the permanent form of the spell, I don't see a reason to change the gear back because gear (inanimate objects) isn't a creature.  Since some artifacts have spirits/souls, those would be a good exception.  For the temp form, I agree that the gear would change back since the magic is a temporary change in status.  In older versions of D&D, there were saving throws for gear/magical gear, so you could have each piece of magical gear save versus spells if, as DM, you want to allow that.

Comment: "anything so transformed keeps all its class levels and abilities" is actually "any creature" not "any thing" since that part is in the creature to creature section of the spell description.

Comment: Note that you need to make the warrior 10th level at least for this to be a problem.  Otherwise, you turn your toad warrior into a rock, and the rock into the level 9 warrior.  Of course, the real solution is to squish the toad, ending the spell, but w/e

Comment: I think that toad is still ninth level since the first polymorph will revert on reduction to 0 hp.

Comment: Does the fact that multiple copies of the same spell don't stack (Player's Handbook p. 205) change using True Polymorph on a previously permanently True Polymorphed being? If the latter casting is deemed to be "most potent", should it undo the first casting, so that when this non-permanent casting ends, the warrior returns (as if the first effect had been dispelled?)

Comment: @SnoringFrog Good question, and maybe "overwrite" fits better than "undo" in this case.  (I think you have the makings of a good question right there.  )

Comment: Luckily, the whole question is completely negated by the adjusted wording of the spell, which specifies that it can be dispelled. So 9th level dispel, and you are good to go. All items and equipment are back too.

Answer (score 28):

## No, you can't *true polymorph* into yourself.

*True Polymorph* (PHB, p. 283):

> If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, the new form can be **any kind** you choose.

The word "kind" seems to be pretty important here, so let's see if any other spells or other rules use it in this way:

*Antipathy/Sympathy* (PHB p. 214):

> Then specify a **kind** of intelligent creature, such as red dragons, goblins, or vampires.

*Locate Creature* (PHB p. 256):

> The spell can ... the nearest creature of a specific **kind** (such as a human or a unicorn) ..

*Special Purpose* (sentient magic items) (DMG p. 216):

> *Protector:* The item seeks to defend a particular race or **kind of creature**, such as elves or druids.

*Wand of Orcus* (DMG p. 227):

> While attuned to the wand, Orcus can summon any **kind of undead**, not just skeletons and zombies.

Examples we have of "kinds of creatures" are: red dragons, goblins, vampires, humans, unicorns, elves, druids, skeletons, zombies. So, that implies that that's the level of choice a spellcaster has when casting True Polymorph. *True polymorph* doesn't let you change a creature into a *specific* other creature, just a creature of some (specific) kind. *Shapechange* is limited to "average examples" of a creature, and nothing indicates that the *polymorph* spells permit any other kind of specificity.

In the case of a warrior *true polymorph*ed into a toad, the options are:

- Dispelling the *true polymorph* spell, which will restore the warrior to its original form.
- *True polymorph*ing the warrior into some other form, of which they will be an average example. If they are made into their original race, they will be an average member of that race with no class or levels, average attribute scores, and their original alignment and memories.
- Kill the toad and then cast *true resurrection*, which will "create a new body if the original no longer exists."

Comment: I like 'kill the toad and cast true resurrection" (if you have the 25,000 GP diamond) as an approach.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can true polymorph yourself into yourself, as *you* are a *kind* of creature.  As for people who use other *completely different descriptions from completely different spells* to reason that a similar word usage they all share makes the word use of the other *completely different spell* in question the same as said *completely different spells*, you are completely different from being far sighted. Emphasis on the *completely different* here.

But ultimately it comes down to what the DM will allow.

Comment: I think you need to support your claim that any one person is a *kind* of person. The other answer (which I think is the one you are refering to) uses other spells as precedent to understand the term in the system. Arguing that words shouldn't be expected to have consistent meaning seems rather counterproductive to me. Also, we generally expect answers to fully answer the question independently of eachother, so I'll suggest you [edit] yours to do that.

Comment: On the other hand, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I think you may be on to something here - the game uses the term "Creature type" in the MM (humanoid, beast, dragon, undead) so you might want to address the points on 'kind' with a reference to *creature type* - or not.  Up to you.  It's a pity that the game text in the PHB used kind rather than type, but they went with the "normal English" thing and I guess didn't see this kind of question coming up.