# Paladin's Find Steed was True Polymorphed

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, polymorph, mount

The paladin in the party I DM for uses the Find Steed spell to summon a saber toothed tiger mount (I'm a nice DM).  The spell says:

> You summon a spirit that assumes the form of an unusually intelligent,
>   strong, and loyal steed, creating a long-lasting bond with it [...]
>   When the steed drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind
>   no physical form.

From this I interpret it as that if the creature dies, the same spirit can be resummoned.

But what would happen if this steed was then True Polymorphed into a small stone statue?

Would the statue need to be broken before it could be summoned again, or would the same spirit not be able to be summoned again?

Comment: Related - [Can a spirit, ghost, or other incorporeal creature be polymorphed?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90582/9399)

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6534). Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers (and the comments correcting them) have been removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, if the steed is True Polymorphed into a statue, then its HP must be brought to 0 (by breaking the statue), or the Paladin dismiss the steed as an action before re-summoning.

> When the steed drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. You can also dismiss your steed at any time as an action, causing it to disappear. In either case, casting this spell again summons the same steed, restored to its hit point maximum.

So, the spell True Polymorph turns that creature into stone. Concentration is held for an hour, the horse is a statue; but it is also still the spirit (creature) you summoned.

> If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the transformation becomes permanent.

Both spells lasting effects are still in play, even though you're passed the duration. Nothing about *true polymorph* removes the effects of *find steed*. You *should* be able to still dismiss it, or drop its HP (objects have HP also) to 0 by breaking it. Devoid of either of those actions, the spirit is now a rock.

I'd like to think if the steed/familiar is dismissed to the pocket dimension remained a statue, because it is funny and I have no reason to believe otherwise. When summoned again, however, the spirit should assume the form of "an unusually intelligent, strong, loyal steed."

This way, none of the clauses of any of the spells were violated by the letter, and I believe intent, of the rules.

Also, permanent doesn't mean permanent.  The effect can be dispelled by things like dispel magic, so I think ruling sending it back to the pocket dimension by dismissing it also releasing after the hour is a rational ruling:

> True polymorph: recent printings of the PH clarify that "permanent" means the effect lasts until dispelled.

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/723569059640401921?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

Comment: What happens if concentration is held for an hour and the effect becomes permanent?  Does the paladin have to cast the spell again and summon a new steed?

Comment: I don't think so....  I'll edit to give my thoughts on why/how.

Comment: Actually, the rules are a bit gray here, [see this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64585/22566) on where a DM has to fill in the gaps with a ruling. *the horse is a statue; but it is also still the spirit (creature) you summoned.* That's not clear, but I personally like your ruling on that ... suggest that you indicate that this is a logical/rational ruling, rather than a fact.

Comment: As I understand your answer, the key to overcoming the permanent statue problem is to dismiss within the hour.  (I think that's what you wrote, and that aligns with my review of how the TP works).

Comment: You don't violate any clause of either spell dismissing the now statued steed even after the TP hour is up.  As for the sentence you call out in your first comment, if you cast dispel magic after the hour you still get the steed back: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/06/are-permanent-effects-dispelled-by-dispel-magic/ (or at least mearls thinks so)... And so do crawford: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/05/13/true-polymorph-rock-into-baby-dragon/  I think I might edit to include.