# Can you bond a different spirit by re-casting Find Steed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin

[Find Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed) allows you to summon a spirit that assumes the form of a steed, creating a long-lasting bond with it. You can't have more than one steed bonded by the spell. It  also says:

> You can also dismiss your steed at any time as an action, causing it to disappear. In either case, casting this spell again summons the same steed, restored to its hit point maximum.
>
> [...]
>
> As an action, you can release the steed from its bond at any time, causing it to disappear.

Assuming your steed became [true polymorphed into a small stone statue](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90576/paladins-find-steed-was-true-polymorphed), and the DM rules that even if you dismiss and resummon it by re-casting the spell, it remains in that form.

Can you release that stone-statue beast from your bond, and bond with another spirit by casting Find Steed again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Yes.

You quoted the relevant rules from the *Find Steed* spell:

> You can't have more than one steed bonded by this spell at a time. As an action, **you can release the steed from its bond at any time, causing it to disappear**.

Under the DM ruling that you exposed, the bond is still active even when the steed is polymorphed, regardless being a statue: you can hence use an action and release the bond, per the spell description, allowing yourself to bond with another spirit on a successive cast of *Find Steed*.

Comment: A cruel fate for the bonded spirit, and a gamey reading of 'bond'. I would hope the (paladin?) cares about the steed enough to not just let them be stone forever, a bond working both ways. But rules wise, good answer.

Comment: @SeriousBri  Thanks! A cruel fate indeed... But I see it as a perfect hook for a side quest, depending on the goodness of the paladin!