# What happens when a non paladin casts a find steed spell from a ring of spell storing

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, paladin, summoning

A paladin casts Find Steed into a ring of Spell Storing.

Another character then casts the Find Steed spell from the ring.

The ring definition says that the spell uses the casting level, save DC etc of the original caster, but "...is otherwise treated as if you [the ring wearer] cast the spell."

So, which of these outcomes makes sense

A. The spell summons the Paladin's Steed. (Assuming it isn't already present)
B. The ring summons the Paladin's Steed, or a copy of it if its already present.
C. The ring summons a new steed for the ring bearer.
D. Something else I haven't considered yet.

EDIT : This question differs to this one [Can a ring of spell storing and access to Find spells produce an endless menagerie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148416/can-a-ring-of-spell-storing-and-access-to-find-spells-produce-an-endless-menager)

Because **I'm asking whether the ring bearer would summon a new steed, or the original steed belonging to the character that put the spell into the ring.**

Comment: Hi Alan, I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: This seems to be a subquestion of the otehr.

Comment: @Trish, from the edit it looks like the asker thinks do, too. I'll reopen it if the other does not help them.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin This is a pretty straightforward duplicate.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike The answer to the other also answers this one, the question however is slightly different about how many steeds one can have with this. As the asker feels the other question is not helping them, I'd rather not be religious about it and hand them a bad experience. But you of course can re-close it if you prefer.

Comment: I tagged your question as dnd-5e, as the other is too, and you did not point out it is for another edition. You should always give the system, so we know for what set of rules to answer. Let me kniw if this one is not right, or change it yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a ring of spell storing and access to Find spells produce an endless menagerie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148416/can-a-ring-of-spell-storing-and-access-to-find-spells-produce-an-endless-menager)

Comment: Related, to the point of whether it can be a different steed or must be the paladin's: [Can you bond a different spirit by re-casting Find Steed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/201945/23547)

Answer (score 8):

### You summon your own steed

Ring of Spell Storing says:

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, **but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell**.

The ownership of the steed is not the slot level, DC, attack bonus or spellcasting ability. Therefore it is not transferred from the original caster: everything else is treated as if you cast the spell, so you get your very own steed, not one belonging to the caster that put the spell into the ring.

Note that once it dies you however cannot re-summon it, as the spell is spent. You need someone to reload the ring with another instance of it first.

Comment: So you have a cool car because your paladin girlfriend got it for you.  That's okay with me...

Comment: Related, in that the answers reflect on what 'as if' means in the context of a ring of spell storing: [Does casting a spell from an Ioun Stone/Ring of Spell Storing require components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124695/23547)