# If I cast True Polymorph on my simulacrum and concentrate for the full duration, will casting Simulacrum again still destroy it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, polymorph, simulacrum

*Simulacrum* states:

> If you cast this spell again, any currently active duplicates you created with this spell are instantly destroyed.

Does this mean that if I take my simulacrum and permanently transform it using *true polymorph* into, say, a dragon, that if I cast *simulacrum* again, it would still instantly destroy that dragon I just produced?

Comment: One important underlying question here is whether you can successfully cast True Polymorph on a simulacrum at all.  True Polymorph works on creatures and nonmagical objects.  A simulacrum certainly isn't a nonmagical object, but is it a creature?  The spell says it's an "illusory duplicate...[which] is a creature, partially real and formed from ice or snow," so the only answer _I_ have is a solid "maybe."

Comment: @gto Yes, a simulacrum is a creature. It's a construct, and constructs are creatures, just like golems and homunculi. Besides which, even if you count it as an object (which is doubtful), *true polymorph* works on objects too.

Comment: user62688  I wasn't thinking it'd be an object -- I was more hooked up on it being illusory.

Comment: @gto There is no rule that says illusory things can't be the target of spells. This illusory thing happens to be a creature that is also a construct. The fact that it is a creature interacts with *true polymorph* by making it a valid target, while the fact that it is illusory is neutral and does not change anything about that relationship.

Answer (score 8):

## A [simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum), even [*true polymporphed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph), gets destroyed upon subsequent casting of *simulacrum*

**tl;dr** True polymorph changes a targets form and stat block.  The property of being a simulacrum is not inherent in either of these, so *true polymorph* does not insulate nor prevent the simulacrum from being destroyed upon a subsequent casting.

### The form of the simulacrum does not affect that it is a simulacrum

It's flexibility with regard to form is already established as it can duplicate any beast or humaniod.  Regardless of form, it's still a simulacrum.

> You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid

### True polymorph for the creature to creature case just changes the form.

> the **new form** can be any kind you choose whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's

The target gets the statistics of the new form.

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form. It retains its alignment and personality.

### Being a simulacrum isn't a [statistic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#MonsterStatistics) of the form.

Being a simulacrum is specified by a magical effect not the stat block of the form it assumes.  So regardless of form or stat block, it's still a simulacrum subject to the effects of the spell that created it including being destroyed upon subsequent casting.

Comment: How can you tell which of the special properties of simulacra are part of their stat block and which aren't? Is there an actual stat block for a simulacrum anywhere?

Comment: @mark_wells Per the DND Beyond link to Simulacrum above, "(other than HP and equipment) the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates, except that it is a construct." If it gained any properties in its stat block aside from the "construct" type, that's where it would be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

yes, your Simulacrum is even when true polymorphed just affected by a spell that can be negated by other means, it is still your simulacrum and would be destroyed. The simulacrums [I´m a Simulacrum] property is not a game statistic that can be changed.

Comment: Shouldn't this be: "Yes, it is still your simulacrum and would be destroyed"?

Answer (score 0):

**Objects or creatures *Truly Polymorphed* are no longer 'currently active duplicates' and would not targeted for 'instant destruction'.**

---

The 5e spell [*Simulacrum*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Simulacrum#content) states:

> If you cast this spell again, any *currently active duplicates* you created with this spell are instantly destroyed. (emphasis added / page 276 *Player's Handbook*)

It is believed this line was added so casters could not make [infinite copies of themselves](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/2g89cp/wish_simulacrum_or_how_to_destroy_the_world_with/). This was a hot topic & all the rage a few years back. When the PhB was reprinted, this line was added so as to give this *high-magic fantasy role-playing game* far more realism, verisimilitude and the respect it deserves (yet still keeping the beast-master ranger [exactly as it was](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/155-is-the-beast-master-broken), of course).

So now, when *Simulacrum* is re-cast (specifically) on the *exact same target-humanoid &/or target-beast*, this magic will also (as a bonus feature?) somehow search all known universes for any possible 'current active duplicates'. Should it find them, it instantly wipes them out (or at least turns them into *rapidly melting snow sculptures*). Of course, anything subject to a [True Polymorph](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/True%20Polymorph#content) could not possibly be a recognizable duplicate of anything anymore. In fact,  StackExchange has made it perfectly clear that one [cannot even *True Polymorph* back into oneself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64578/can-you-permanently-true-polymorph-into-yourself).